# Embedding multiple Youtube videos on different pages problem using JavaScript Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube

Is there a way to embed a multiple videos across different website pages. I'm currently facing in issue where the `onPlayerStateChange(event)` only is active on the initial video and the rest of the video it's unresponsive. Here is how I have it setup.

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var playerInfoList = [{
  id: "player1",
  videoId: 'xxxxxxxx',
  width: 1120,
  height: 630,
  events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange }
}, {
  id: "player2",
  videoId: "xxxxxxxxx",
  width: 1120,
  height: 630,
  events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange }
}, {
  id: "player3",
  videoId: "xxxxxxx",
  width: 1120,
  height: 630,
  events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange }
}];

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

if (typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined') return;

for (var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length; i++) {
    var curplayer = createPlayer(playerInfoList[i]);
    players[i] = curplayer;
} }


/***** For some reason this section only shows up on one video and when you click to go to the next page, where there is another youtube video but the onPlayer State Change(event) is not responsive. It only worked for the initial youtube video ****/

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data === 0) {
         alert("Great it worked");
         players[0].stopVideo();
         players[0].destroy();
         players[0] = null;  // Clear out the reference to the destroyed player
    }
}

var players = new Array();

function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
  return new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
    videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
    width: playerInfo.width,
    height: playerInfo.height,
    events: playerInfo.events,
    playerVars: {
      showinfo: 0,
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Page 1 --->
`<div id="player1"></div>`

Page 2 ---->
`<div id="player2"></div>`

Page 3 ----->
`<div id="player3"></div>`

Any assistance to this problem is appreciated it.

I'm expecting an alert to show up "Great it worked" at the end of each video on each page.